# If I have a 15 min sliding window, how can I collect daily/weekly aggregates?

Tags: algorithm, analytics, sliding-window

I have a 15 min sliding window, and can aggregate at any given time over this data within this window. Due to memory constraints, I can't increase the size of the window. I still think I should be able to get aggregates (like trending items which is basically freq counter etc.) over a day/a week.

It doesn't have to be a very accurate count, just needs to filter out the top 3-5.

1. Will running a cron job every 15 mins and putting it into 4 (15min) counters work?
2. Can I get update some kind of a rolling counter over the aggregate?
3. Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: What's the data?  (A series of numeric values?)  What "aggregates" do you want to compute?  Some (like the sum or average) are easy to compute in O(1) space with a single pass, while others (like the median) are provably impossible to compute in O(1) space with a single pass.

Comment: Can you provide additional details?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is an exponentially decaying moving average.  Like is done for the Unix load average.  (See http://www.howtogeek.com/194642/understanding-the-load-average-on-linux-and-other-unix-like-systems/ for an explanation.)

What you do is pick a constant `0 < k < 1` then update every 5 minutes as follows:

```
moving_average = k * average_over_last_5_min + (1-k) * moving_average
```

This will behave something like an average over the last `5/k` minutes.  So if you set `k = 1/(24.0 * 60.0 / 5.0) = 0.00347222222222222` then you get roughly a daily moving average.  Divide that by 7 and you get roughly a weekly moving average.

The averages won't be exact, but should work perfectly well to identify what things are trending recently.